# Finding logic operators

Tags: java, parsing

We get the search string from the UI. Based on the search parameters we need to create a back-end query. This is similar to "Feed Item Query Language(FIQL)". I have wrote the code to find the logical operators in the search parameters like `||` (or operator) and `;` (And operator).

The code is working as expected, but I want to know if we can improve the code.

For example, the below search parameter:

- And operator (`;`) is outer group
- Or operator (`||`) is inner group

> ```
> status:eq(A);sourceKey.entityId:eq(36KAG);[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB)||hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)]
> ```

```
package com.guthyrenker.soma.ws.rest.v1.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class TestOperator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String outerOperator = null;

        String filter = "status:eq(A)";
        outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals("Outer operator is and condition",";", outerOperator);

        filter = "status:eq(A);";
        outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals("Outer operator is and condition",";", outerOperator);

        filter = "status:eq(A);sourceKey.entityId:eq(36KAG);[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB)||hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)]";
        outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals("Outer operator is and condition",";", outerOperator);

        filter =
                "status:eq(A)||sourceKey.entityId:eq(36KAG)||[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB);hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)]||[productLineCode:eq(YB);productLineCode:eq(PB)]";
        outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals("Outer operator is or condition","||", outerOperator);

        filter =
                "status:eq(A)||sourceKey.entityId:eq(36KAG)||[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB);hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)]||[productLineCode:eq(YB);productLineCode:eq(PB)]||readyDate:eq(2014-01-01T00:00:00)";
        outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals("Outer operator is or condition","||", outerOperator);

        filter = "[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB);hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)]||[productLineCode:eq(YB);productLineCode:eq(PB)]";
        outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals("Outer operator is or condition","||", outerOperator);

        filter = "[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB)||hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)];[productLineCode:eq(YB)||productLineCode:eq(PB)]";
        outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals("Outer operator is and condition",";", outerOperator);

        filter =
                "status:eq(A);sourceKey.entityId:eq(36KAG);[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB)||hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)];readyDate:eq(2014-01-01T00:00:00)";
        outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals("Outer operator is and condition",";", outerOperator);

        // Exception Cases

        filter = "[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB);hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)];[productLineCode:eq(YB)||productLineCode:eq(PB)]";
        try {
            outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }

        try {
        filter =
                "[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB)||hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)];[productLineCode:eq(YB)||productLineCode:eq(PB)||[productLineCode:eq(ZB)]]";
            outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }

        try {
            filter = "status:eq(A);status:eq(P)||status:eq(C)";
            outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }

        try {
            filter = "status:eq(A);sourceKey.entityId:eq(36KAG);[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB)||hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)]||status:eq(C)";
            outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }

        try {
            filter = "status:eq(A)-sourceKey.entityId:eq(36KAG);[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB)||hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)]";
            outerOperator = validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
    }

    public static String validateAndFindSubgroupOperator(String filter) {

        String previousOperator = null;
        String curOperator = null;

        String REGEX_SUBGROUP = "\\[(.*?)\\]";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX_SUBGROUP);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filter);

        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group();
            matches.add(group);
        }


        for(String subGroupFilter : matches){
            curOperator = validateGroup(subGroupFilter);
            if(previousOperator!=null && !curOperator.equals(previousOperator)){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("All subgroups should have same operator.");
            }else {
                 String subGroupNoBraces = subGroupFilter.substring(1, subGroupFilter.length()-1);
                 if(subGroupNoBraces.indexOf("[")>0 || subGroupNoBraces.indexOf("]")>0){
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nested subgroups are not allowed.");
                 }
            }
            previousOperator = curOperator;
        }
        return curOperator;
    }

    public static String validateAndFindOuterOperator(String filter) {

        String REGEX_SUBGROUP = "\\[(.*?)\\]";

        filter = filter.replaceAll(REGEX_SUBGROUP, "");

        return validateGroup(filter);
    }

    public static String validateGroup(String filter) {

        // Parameter regular expression
        String REGEX_PARAMETER = "([A-Za-z0-9.]+):([A-Za-z]+)(\\({1})(\\')?([a-zA-Z0-9-+,:]+)(\\')?(\\){1})";

        if ((filter.indexOf(";") >= 0 && filter.indexOf("||") >= 0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected same operator, but found different operator.");
        } else if (filter.indexOf("||") >= 0) { // or logical operator is found for the subgroups
            return "||";
        } else if (filter.indexOf(";") >= 0 || filter.matches(REGEX_PARAMETER)) { // and logical operator is found for the subgroups
            return ";";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Filter is not valid.");
        }
    }

    private static String validateAndGetOuterOperator(String filter){
        String subGroupOperator = validateAndFindSubgroupOperator(filter);
        String outerGroupOperator = validateAndFindOuterOperator(filter);
        return outerGroup;
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. Your code does not compile (you are returning `outerGroup` in `validateAndGetOuterOperator`, but it doesn't exist). Is this maybe just a copy-paste error?

Comment: I have fixed that issue, i just renamed it.

Comment: can you fix it here in the question as well? I'm assuming you want to return `outerGroupOperator` (in that case, all your tests pass), but why are you calling `validateAndFindSubgroupOperator` then? For that matter, that method seems to be entirely unused.

Answer (score 2):

**Wrapper Methods**

Methods that don't do anything except call another method should be removed. `validateAndGetOuterOperator` seems to be such a method.

**Naming**

- only class level constants should be all uppercase.
- what's the difference between `find` and `get` in your method names?
- all your method names start with `validate`. Either just remove it (I think the names don't lose meaning without it), or remove it and change your class name (`LogicValidator` or something).

**Unit Tests**

Create actual unit tests. It's great that you have tests, but because they are all in `main`, as soon as one test fails, the other tests are not executed anymore. It should look something like this:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import test2.TestOperator;

public class TestOperatorTest {

    @Test
    public void noAnd() {
        String filter = "status:eq(A)";
        String outerOperator = TestOperator.validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals(";", outerOperator);
    }

    @Test
    public void trailingAnd() {
        String filter = "status:eq(A);";
        String outerOperator = TestOperator.validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals(";", outerOperator);
    }

    @Test
    public void andAndInnerOr() {
        String filter = "status:eq(A);sourceKey.entityId:eq(36KAG);[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB)||hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)]";
        String outerOperator = TestOperator.validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
        Assert.assertEquals(";", outerOperator);
    }

    @Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void invalidBecauseX() {
        String filter = "[hostProductLineCode:eq(YB);hostProductLineCode:eq(PB)];[productLineCode:eq(YB)||productLineCode:eq(PB)]";
        String outerOperator = TestOperator.validateAndGetOuterOperator(filter);
    }
    // [...]

}
```

Note that I removed your comments, as they were not that helpful in determining what a test does. I did give the test methods names that I think describe the test cases better.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expressions could use some work:

> ```
> public static String validateAndFindOuterOperator(String filter) {
>
>     String REGEX_SUBGROUP = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
>
>     filter = filter.replaceAll(REGEX_SUBGROUP, "");
>
>     return validateGroup(filter);
> }
> ```

The above code should have the regular expression compiled outside the method, as a constant:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_SUBGROUP = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");

public static String validateAndFindOuterOperator(String filter) {
    filter = REGEX_SUBGROUP.matcher(filter).replaceAll("");
    return validateGroup(filter);
}
```

Similarly, the pattern:

```
    // Parameter regular expression
    String REGEX_PARAMETER = "([A-Za-z0-9.]+):([A-Za-z]+)(\\({1})(\\')?([a-zA-Z0-9-+,:]+)(\\')?(\\){1})";
```

should be streamlined a lot more. There are three things I suggest. First, make it a Pattern constant, second, the `{1}` is redundant, along with all the grouping braces. Third, make it case-insensitive to reduce the repetition.

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PARAMETER = Pattern.compile(
      "[a-z0-9.]+:[a-z]+\\('?[a-z0-9-+,:]+'?\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Note that the above pattern (and your original code) will match the invalid input `ABC:DEF('onequote)`. I would fix it by having the expression:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PARAMETER = Pattern.compile(
      "[a-z0-9.]+:[a-z]+\\(('[a-z0-9-+,:]+'|[a-z0-9-+,:]+)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

which allows either quoted values, or unquoted values, but not half-quoted values.